# Scala akka-http client Timeout error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, akka-http

I have a Scala Play application that uses Akka and queries a REST server. The request can take a long time to respond and I am getting timeouts:

"The server was not able to produce a timely response to your request. Please try again in a short while!"

I have tried using Play WSClient and kaka-http client and get the same error and I have set every timeout property I can find.

The WSClient is Injected into the Actor and I call it this was in my Actor

```
val resp = ws.url("myurl").withRequestTimeout(Duration.Inf).get()
resp pipeTo self
```

And I tried:

```
Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "myurl"))
```

And then pipe this to self but still the timeout.

In application.conf I have set:

```
play.ws.timeout.connection = 3600 s
play.ws.timeout.request = 3600 s
play.ws.timeout.idle = 3600 s
akka.http.server.idle-timeout = 3600 s
akka.http.http-connection-pool.idle-timeout = 3600 s
akka.http.http-connection-pool.client.idle-timeout = 3600 s
akka.http.server.request-timeout = 3600 s
akka.http.client.idle-timeout = 3600 s
akka.http.client.connecting-timeout = 3600 s
```

I am not sure what else I can do. I have even tried

```
Await.resutl(rest, Duration.Inf)
```

But this does not help. If anyone has any idea on what I can try it would be appreciated. I am using Akka 2.4.4 and Play 2.5.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was on the server side which is also an Akka application. I have set the server connection timeout and that has fixed the problem.